# How to use a if statement in a div using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

If I remove the div tag from the source code below my application runs with no error. But it displays an empty cell (which is correct). I just want to hide this if the cells are empty.

**Thymeleaf html**

```
<div th:object="${AppPortModel.Status}" th:if="${AppPortModel.Status} == 'CRITICAL'">  
<h3>
MONITORING
</h3>

<table id ="apCritTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th> HostName </th>
        <th> Port Name</th>
        <th> Port Listening Count </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="AppPortModel, iterStat : ${showap}" th:if="${AppPortModel.Status == 'CRITICAL'}">
        <td th:text ="${AppPortModel.Status}"></td>
         <td th:text="${AppPortModel.host}">${AppPortModel.host}</td>
        <td th:text="${AppPortModel.portOwner}"></td>
         <td th:text="${AppPortModel.count}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**AppPortModel**

```
public class AppPortModel implements Comparable {
private String Status;
private String host;
private String portName;
private String plCount;

//getters and setters

@Override int compareTo(Object o) {
return //stuff
 }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getdata() throws IOException {
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("showap", apList);
            return model;
}
```

**AppPortList**

```
@Component
    public class AppPortList {      

   @Value("#{'$APP_SERVERS_PORT}'.split('@!')}")
   private String[] apServerArray;
   @Value("#{'${APP_SERVER_MONITORING_LIST}'.split('@!')}")
   private String[] appServerPortsList;
@PostConstruct
    public List<AppPortModel> getAppPortList() {

    final int MYTHREADS = 80;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

    ApplicationPort.resetData();

    try {

        for (int z = 0; z < apServerArray.length; z++) {    

            String apServer = apServerArray[z];
            String[] portListArray=appServerPortsList[z].split(",");
            ApplicationPort apWorker = new ApplicationPort(apServer, portListArray);
            executor.execute(apWorker);
        }   
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in AppPortList");
            }
            finally {
            executor.shutdown();

            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            }               
            logger.info("\nFinished all threads in App Port. ");    
            }
            return ApplicationPort.getData();               
        }
```

**Snippet of Class App**

```
static List<AppPortModel> apData = new ArrayList<AppPortModel>();

public static List<AppPortModel> getData() {
    return apData;
}

public static void setData(List<AppPortModel> apData) {
    ApplicationPort.apData = apData;
}

public static void resetData(){
    apData = new ArrayList<AppPortModel>();
}

public ApplicationPort(String apServer, String[] portListArray) {
this.apServer = apServer;   
this.portListArray = portListArray;

}
```

This table will populate if AppPortModel.Status is CRITICAL. I am trying to hide this table if there is no values in this table. If I just have a regular div tag my code will run but I will have a awkward head and table row heads on my page with empty cells.

**Attempt**

I tried adding some th logic into my div tag, but I receive an null error.

```
 <div th:object="${AppPortModel.Status}" th:if="${AppPortModel.Status == 'CRITICAL'}">
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<div th:if="${Status} == 'CRITICAL'">
```

This script would hide my div tag. Even if I have Status = to CRITICAL it would still hide the table.

Comment: Can you please post the model class for AppPortModel? And  how do you bring the object to the model? Did you check the object is not null. Post your relevant controller code. Your error message says AppPortModel object is null, and you're trying to access a field from a null instance. Please post full stacktrace.

Comment: Hi Lucky, you've found my post! If I dont use the th:if in the div tag, my application runs. It will display nothing because my <tr> displays only if status = 'CRITICAL'.  I will add all requested file right now.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, you basically want to hide the table if the list is empty right?

Comment: Yes, hide the div tag so it hides the <h3> also

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check whether the list is empty using the following condition expression. Assuming the object showap is a List type,

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(showap)}">
     --content--
</div>
```

Your h3 tag and table goes inside this div.

`#lists` is a thymeleaf utility class. Refer http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/expression/Lists.html for more options. You can alternatively use size() method and check for list length.

Comment: The showap list is not null, It contains a list of values with different Status eg; CRITICAL, BAD, and OK. That's why I want to show div if a Status value = CRITICAL. if not then don't show. Just like what I did in the <tr tag> drawing out all the list that contains "CRITICAL".

Comment: Yes it will not display the table if the list has no items. i.e. list size is 0. If your list showap contains values then table will be displayed.

Comment: Hmmm, that wouldn't work for me. my list will always have items. I have two more tables like this one for BAD and one for OK. They all share the same list "showap". Looks like I have to revise my logic and put them in separate list right?

Comment: Yes that would work. If you have theree div elements for three tables you can create theree different list based on the status and check the size as in my answer based on which the table would be displayed.

Comment: What if my list is a generic list = List<AppPortModel> apData. I add all the data that are being received with a simple line of apData.add(new AppPortModel(Status,Server,pName,count). Would I have to create new pojos for each?

Comment: If the list is of type AppPortModel it's not a generic list. Check the status and add it in corresponding list object. If status is critical add it to list1, if status is Bad add it to list2 and so on. No need to create new POJO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130046/discussion-between-jackie-and-lucky).